What are alternatives to Android File Transfer to transfer files from Android onto Macs?
What's up with Android File Transfer? Went to the download site but couldn't find the link. I saw on the forums it's not supported anymore.
What are some other ways I can transfer files from my phone to my Mac? Any apps you recommend instead?

https://openmtp.ganeshrvel.com or https://github.com/localsend/localsend

Google Drive is probably going to be your cheapest option.

If you're technically-minded, one way is SSH over wifi.  It takes a little set-up, but it's all free and open-source, and is very flexible.
You can run an SSH daemon (server) on Android, and then your Mac (and any other machines you want) can connect to it.  The connection is secure (authenticated and encrypted), and you can transfer/synchronise/back up files in both directions, launch an interactive shell, and many other things.
An SSH daemon is a small program that runs in the background and listens for incoming SSH connections.  One way to get it on your Android phone is to install Termux, which includes a minimal Linux environment; you can then run sshd from its terminal, which will launch the daemon.  (If your phone is rooted, you can run sshd as root, which will then give access to all your files; otherwise, it'll only be able to see user files.)  But there are several other ways; search the web for ‘Android sshd’.
You can then use any SSH client on the Mac, which can be as simple as running ssh (to get a shell session) or scp (to transfer files) or rsync (to synchronise folder structures) from the Terminal.
Alternatively, you could run sshd on your Mac (e.g. by enabling System Preferences → Sharing → Remote Login), and connect to that from your phone.  I haven't done that, but a quick search for ‘Android ssh’ shows many SSH clients for Android too.
(I prefer to run the server on my phone, as it means I can initiate a transfer at any time from my Mac; I have several scripts for synchronising and backing up the phone.)
